# How do I read a Maven dependency tree

Tags: java, maven

I have servlet-api version 2.5 as provided scope in pom.xml. Here is part of the dependency:tree output of my project. What does "version managed from 2.3; scope managed from compile" mean?

```
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided (version managed from 2.3; scope managed from compile)
```

Does that mean there is some transitive dependency on version 2.3 on my classpath? My [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file does not have servlet-api jar at all, but I do use old version of [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) 2.5.4. I suspect the Spring framework depends on servlet-api 2.3.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The message basically means that the `version` of servlet-api would have transitively been 2.3 (so basically in commons-logging's pom they define servlet-api with version 2.3), but that version 2.5 was specifically asked for in your project, so that is what was used.

Same goes for the scope. In commons-logging's pom it is defined with scope `compile`, but you have it defined with scope `provided`, so again that is the scope that was used.

Comment: Except in my case (spring-data-mongodb) I can't find where I've overridden the managed version.

Comment: @OrangeDog I've had similar issue. I found that older version of httpclient came from spring-boot-starter-parent pom.

Comment: Note that they can be overridden "in a parent" pom as well, so be sure to double check there also...

Comment: is there a way to find out where the version was overridden? its not in my parent

Comment: @AndreasRadauer: `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true > pom-effective.xml` lists the whole information resolved by maven - the "effective" POM without further external dependencies needed, and in verbose mode includes comments about which recipe and line it came from. However, for me it printed the version it settled on using - no mention of others it decided to discard (or why)...

Answer (score 9):

It means that your project has overridden the `version` and `scope` from other dependencies.