# mvn - project uses incorrect dependency version, even though it is explicitely defined

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, version

I have this very bad problem - there are three projects A, B, C. C has a version 1.0.5. I want to use this one. A and B both have defined this dependency version explicitely within their POMS. However, when running, they use 1.0.2.

They all share one R root POM, but this should be irrelevant.

Legend:

- A - portlets
- B - persistence
- C - textProcessing
- R - myProjectRoot (root pom)

When I run main() of project A, it tries to initialize spring context, which imports B context which in turn includes C context. In version 1.0.2 C context was including B context, which caused a cyclic import exception like this:

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:persistenceApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [portletsApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:textProcessingApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:persistenceApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/myProject/TextProcessing/1.0.2/TextProcessing-1.0.2.jar!/textProcessingApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Detected cyclic loading of URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml] - check your import definitions!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
                    ........
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.myProject.myProject.portlets.demo.SolrStatementTest.main(SolrStatementTest.java:27)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:textProcessingApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:persistenceApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/myProject/TextProcessing/1.0.2/TextProcessing-1.0.2.jar!/textProcessingApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Detected cyclic loading of URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml] - check your import definitions!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
    at 
..........
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:persistenceApplicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/myProject/TextProcessing/1.0.2/TextProcessing-1.0.2.jar!/textProcessingApplicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Detected cyclic loading of URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml] - check your import definitions!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)

    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Detected cyclic loading of URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/com/myProject/PersistenceModule/1.2.6-SNAPSHOT/PersistenceModule-1.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/persistenceApplicationContext.xml] - check your import definitions!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)

    ... 42 more
```

A (portlets) POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <name>portlets</name>
    <groupId>
com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>portlets</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.13.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>
com.myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProjectRoot</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myProject.com/scm/svn/portlets/portlets</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://myProject.com/scm/svn/portlets/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
   ... many dependencies here


        <!-- ============== myProject MODULES ============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>PersistenceModule</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>EntityModule</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>Translator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>WordNetUtil</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

B POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <name>PersistenceModule</name>
    <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>PersistenceModule</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProjectRoot</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myProject.com/scm/svn/persistence/PersistenceModule</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/ratedPosts/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/testingMaterial/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/tempmyProjectFLD/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/ratedPosts/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/testingMaterial/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/tempmyProjectFLD/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://myProject.com/scm/svn/persistence/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MONGO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject.harvest.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-libpst</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>TextProcessing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- myProject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>EntityModule</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Parsing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Social Network libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

C POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>TextProcessing</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>TextProcessing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProjectRoot</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myProject.com/scm/svn/utils-translation/TextProcessing/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>Translator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>EntityModule</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

R (root) POM:
iherited by all other poms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>myProjectRoot</name>
    <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProjectRoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <powermock.version>1.5.6</powermock.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.6.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- NEXUS configuration -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>https://myProject.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://myProject.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myProject.com/scm/svn/myProjectroot/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <!-- Global settings of maven plugins across myProject. Can be overriden with custom plugin managment, not recommended. -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin> 
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Used for setting global versions of projects used across myProject. 

    In your project only declare groupId and artifactId to use a dependency with 
    a version and configuration used in this pom. -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

................................ many more..................

            <!-- myProject DEPENDENCIES -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
                <artifactId>EntityModule</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
                <artifactId>PersistenceModule</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myProject.analysis</groupId>
                <artifactId>ContentModule</artifactId>
                <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>myProject</groupId>
                <artifactId>TextProcessing</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- harvests -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
                <artifactId>DocumentHarvest</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
                <artifactId>harvest-Twitter</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

I noticed that even though my pom within the particular snapshot being used contains the 1.0.5 C dependency, it still shows that the transitively imported dependency being used is 1.0.2. See screenshot: 
[image]
You can see on the image, that the TextProcessing 1.0.2 is VIA PersistenceModule. But also that the dependency being used (the pom of it is opened) has the dependency set to 1.0.5. I opened the POM FROM the dependency tree, not from the project itself to ensure, that I am really really looking at the dependency of the particularily used snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that in my parent pom, which was used (0.10) was the C project defined as 1.0.2.

The A project had B, which was referencing C in 1.0.5, so transitively A should have C in 1.0.5, however, A took C version 1.0.2 from R (from Parent/Root). Obviously, it had higher priority. It probably is because maven takes the dependency version depending on how deep it has to go until it hits the version. The smallest level of depth (first hit) is chosen, which is 1.0.2, which was my problem.

The solution is what I should have done in the first place - remove my own modules from parent. Now it takes the good version transitively.

I read somewhere it is a bad practice to hold your own modules in a parent to resolve versions between them. After a long time I actually hit the reasons by experience, why it is a bad practice.

Thanks @sorencito for the recommendation to check with mvn dependency:tree. It showed me a structure, which helped me google [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20189350/1920149) which made me think about the old parent version.

Answer (score 0):

Your portlets pom depends on PersistenceModule in version 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT, but it should be 1.2.6-SNAPSHOT (which defines the dependency to TextProcessing in version 1.0.5). I suppose that your version 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT depends on the older version 1.0.2 of TextProcessing which is causing the error.

Btw, you should remove all versions from dependency declarations which are managed in the parent pom. I'd recommend doing this consistently for all dependencies.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT depends on 1.0.5 as well. I also use 1.2.6 currently and it still does not work

Comment: I do remove dependency versions, which are in the parent pom, however not for the intermodular dependencies, only external, since if I would want to have top versions in parent, I would have to bump parent and thus bump children and thus bump parent etc.

Comment: @Ev0oD If they are intermodular dependencies I recommend using one and te same version. However, I suppose you did all the tricks like reimporting all mvn projects in IJ IDEA, mvn dependency:tree to see where the dependency comes from, mvn clean and so on, right?

Comment: It is not feasible to use the same version. many developers develop the modules and they release version upon implementing functionality etc. and we raise the versions of their modules per needs. I did not import IDEA - I do not use it, AFAIK it is not free. I did not try the dependency:tree, I will try that now. mvn clean of course all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in such multi-module projects, where you have POM with parent child relationship, we should use Dependency Management. Use `<dependencyManagement>` in your parent POM. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I do use it. Check the parent pom, it is there. And was there at the time of your comment.