# maven dependency tree - version managed

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In my project I see the following when issuing `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`:

```
[INFO] |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile (version managed from 2.7.0)
[INFO] |  |     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
```

Does this `version managed` mean Xalan 2.7.2 overrides 2.7.0?

Note: In my parent pom I have 2.7.2 under `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read maven dependency tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189350/how-to-read-maven-dependency-tree)

Comment: I read the post before asking this question. I was not able to understand the answers posted and I was not able to further ask question under that post.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, your understanding is correct.