# spring-boot-starter-web 3.0.1 > spring-core 5.3.23 class loader method not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'
```

Here is the snapshot of the dependency hierarchy:
[image]

I understand that with spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.1 we need spring-core:6.0.1 or above. How to correct this? As the hierarchy shows the spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.1 is translative dependent on spring-core:5.3.23. I am using jdk 17.

Comment: Please share your pom.xml or build.gradle.

Comment: And see if this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192757/796761 Basically, it appears your pom has conflicting dependencies.

Comment: Please inspect your (verbose) "effective pom" someone/-thing (in your pom hierarchy) must set/manage this (wrong) version ..